# Unexplained infinity error

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an error that tells me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

so i get rid of the ;...

...it gives me this error:
    `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for`

here's the code that goes wrong:

```
function draw() { 
    paintCanvas(); 
    for(var i = 0; i &lt; paddles.length; i++) { 
    p = paddles[i];
```

the broken semicolon is just after the PaintCanvas() bit.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace.

Comment: Except for missing the closing parts, the code you've posted seems fine

Comment: Please, try to write a descriptive title for your **question**, so that others can help you.

Comment: `<` sign in your loop is converted to `&lt;`

Answer (score 10):

```
    for(var i = 0; i &lt; paddles.length; i++) {
                     ^^^^---- HTML entities are **NOT** valid in JS code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
function draw() {
    paintCanvas();
    for (var i = 0; i < paddles.length; i++) {
        p = paddles[i];
    }
}
```

Proper indentation and a decent IDE usually help finding missing braces or syntax errors.